# How to enable http (not just https) in wordpress?

Tags: permalinks, ssl, https

My wp-config.php file contains

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

but all my permalinks are https: by default.
[image]

I want the site to be accessible by http.  What do I need to change please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the wordpress address and siteurl in Dashboard > Settings > General